# Как оптимизировать работу с state-ом в react , redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть state в котором есть свойство cartProducts, значением которого является массив из объектов (товары магазина).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть компонент input при помощи которого можно менять кол-во одного товара.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот собственно сам этот компонент input. Проблема в чем:
так как в useSelector приходит не значение, а массив с объектами, это означает что при любом изменении компонент будет перерендерен. Так оно и происходит, при нажатии на один input, обновляются все. Как сделать так, чтобы обновлялся только тот input,  у которого в объекте менялось свойство count

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ваши компоненты обновлются из-за того, что обновляется родительский компонент, потому, что в компоненте ProductInput обновлется только когда изменяется count, props или происходит ререндер родительского компонента. Вы можете обернуть компонент ProductInput в HOC React.memo. Prop id, как я понимаю не будет меняться, но это позволит не обновлять дочерние компоненты. Хоть и будет бесполезная проверка на идентичность prevProps и currentProps, но при таком раскладе также можно использовать React.memo